# How to loop a function in r?

Tags: r

```
Example: 
a <- function(b,c,d,e,f){ 
if(f == 1){
  Value1 <- b * c * d * e
  return(Value1)
}else if(f == 2){
  Value2 <- b * c * d
  return(Value2) 
}else{
  Value3 <- 0 
}
}
```

Assume I would like to analyze the relationship between Value2 and d for d = seq(0,2,0.05) if b,c,e are fixed and I can't change the function.
So I would like to plot a graph with Value2 on the y-axis and d on the x-axis. 
 What I tried: Construct a vector and combine them with seq(0,2,0.05)

```
ValueChange <- c() 

for( i in seq(0,2,0.05)){
  ValueChange <- a(10,2,i,5,2)
}
ValueChange
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `for` loop should be like below

```
for( i in seq(0,2,0.05)){
  ValueChange <- c(ValueChange,a(10,2,i,5,2))
}
```

where the newly generated value `a(10,2,i,5,2)` will be updated and appended to `ValueChange`

---

Or a more efficient way via `sapply`

```
ValueChange <- sapply(seq(0,2,0.05),function(i) a(10,2,i,5,2))
```

Comment: Isn't that an `O(n^2)` way of creating the vector?

Comment: @JohnColeman I know it is inefficient. An efficient way might be `sapply`. I just want to show OP what happened in the `for` loop